# Create a group conditioning on a row

Tags: r

I'm trying to keep/split groups in a data frame which meet a condition for a specific row; the data.frame looks like:

```
COW   PARITY    DFC    ABCS
1        1       1      0.5
1        1       2        1
1        1       3     0.25
1        2       1     -0.3
1        2       2      0.5
```

I would like to create groups with the same value of `COW` and parity for which

```
ABCS>0 for DFC==1
```

I try with `group_by` + `filter` but I'm unable to correctly split.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with logical subsetting, like this:

```
df1[df1$COW==df1$PARITY & df1$ABCS>0 & df1$DFC==1,]
#  COW PARITY DFC ABCS
#1   1      1   1  0.5
```

This considers three conditions, connected with a logical AND (`&`). First, the value of `COW` and `PARITY` should be equal, then the value of `ABCS` should be greater than 0, and finally the value of `DFC` should be equal to one. In the example posted above, only one observation (row) fulfills these three conditions.

**edit**

Following the suggestion by @docendodiscimus the command can be shortened and rendered more legible by using `with()`, for instance like this:

```
df1[with(df1,COW==PARITY & ABCS>0 & DFC==1),]
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(COW = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
PARITY = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), DFC = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
ABCS = c(0.5, 1, 0.25, -0.3, 0.5)), 
.Names = c("COW", "PARITY", "DFC", "ABCS"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```